# Google maps api with destination textboxes

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

Here is a link to my code: http://www.canning.co.nz/Mapping/Code.txt

Sorry, it is in text format, for some reason I had some trouble in pasting it into this forum.

It is working nicely. However, I am after a little bit of help with a problem that I am having. Currently, the textboxes come up for the start and destination after I click on a button. I am wanting to have these textboxes all display when the page loads and then just press on the button and the route will be displayed.

Can I please have some help with this? Or is there a better example that I can have a look at somewhere on the net?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt your current example to work this way. First you need a couple more JavaScript functions. You can place these below the directions() function.

JavaScript:

```
function searchFunc(point) { 
    if (point) {
        if (state==1) {doEnd(point)}
        if (state==0) {doStart(point)}
    } else {
        var result=geo.getCache().get(search);
        if (result) {
            var reason="Code "+result.Status.code;
            if (reasons[result.Status.code]) {
                reason = reasons[result.Status.code]
            }
        } else {
          var reason = "";
        } 
        alert('Could not find "'+search+ '" ' + reason);
    }
}

function GLoad() {          
    var search = document.getElementById("search").value,
        search2 = document.getElementById("search2").value;
    addresses[0] = search;
    addresses[4] = search2;
    geo.getLatLng(search, searchFunc);
    geo.getLatLng(search2, searchFunc);        
}
```

Next you need to remove the three calls to handleState(). There is one call right below the function declaration. The other two are in doStart() and doEnd(). You can also remove the function itself. This function was doing the show/hide of the fields and buttons.

Finally, you need to update the  tag to call GLoad().

```
<body onload="GLoad()" onunload="GUnload()">
```

Now if you click Get Directions the page should function the same as before, except we've taken care of the first couple button clicks and all the fields remain visible.

You probably want to also remove the buttons for "Find start address" and "Find destination address" but I wasn't sure. Removing them is as simple as removing the buttons from the HTML.

Feel free to ask any questions. I hope that helps!

Comment: Another question: If I change the values in the textboxes after I have pressed the get directions button once, the new route between the two new values does not get displayed. Can I please have some help with this? Thanks.

Comment: I believe that was a problem already present before my revision. It is a different problem that deserves its own question. Unaccepting my answer because you have more problems in your code will not yield more help.